# Rails 3: when no current_user(no user logged in) friendly_id sends username as :id but controller method does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, friendly-id

I'm using friendly_id gem and it's working properly when I go to a user's profile page as a logged in user:

```
localhost/users/facebookname
```

When I log out and go to the profile page it displays the url same way, no problem. However, when I attempt to display the user's 'liked' posts I run into a problem. Nothing happens.

```
Started GET "/users/facebookname/likes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-08 14:47:23 +0700
  Processing by UsersController#likes as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"facebookname"}
Completed   in 152ms
```

UsersController#likes

```
  def likes
    @title = "Likes"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render "posts/posts", :locals => { :posts => @likes } }
      format.js { respond_with @likes}
    end
  end
```

UsersModel

```
has_friendly_id :username, :use_slug => true, :approximate_ascii => true
```

When I am logged in as a user, and try the same thing, the `Parameters: {"id"=>"facebookname"}` are used the same way, but the controller action uses this with the proper :id and renders @likes. Why is this not happening without a logged in user?

Thank you very much for any insight

Answer (score 1):

You should find user by `username` in your controller:

```
@user = User.find_by_username!(params[:id])
```

Comment: Thank you, I get NoMethodError (undefined method `find_by!'... Why would this be?

Comment: @user1009762 it's my bad, I didn't notice you use Rails 3. Now it should work, after edition.

Comment: Ok thank you, but nothing is still happening when I'm not logged in Started GET "/users/example12/likes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-08 16:30:44 +0700
  Processing by UsersController#likes as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"example12"}
Completed   in 175ms

Comment: And when I open the link in a new tab using html it redirects me to sign in Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-08 16:32:01 +0700
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (6.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 193ms (Views: 10.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)

Comment: ok I found the problem, I have autenticate_user being called hehe, thanks this helped me dig in and see the problem

Comment: @user1009762 Maybe you have some other issues, out of the scope of the original question? Investigate it.